# NameError when assigning instance of model to reference property

Tags: ruby, camping

I'm unable to assign a model instance to a reference property of another model. Relevant code is below:

```
module Blog::Models
    class Post < Base; belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy end
    class User < Base; has_many :posts end
    ...
    class BasicFields < V 1.0
        def self.up
                create_table User.table_name do |t|
                    ...
                end
                create_table Post.table_name do |t|
                    ...
                    t.references :user
                end
        end
        ...
    end
end

module Blog::Controllers
    ...
    class PostEditN
        ...
        def post(post_num)
            @post = Post.find(post_num)
            @user = User.find(@input.user)
            ...
            @post.user = @user # Error thrown: NameError at /post/edit/1 uninitialized constant User
            # @post.user_id = @user.id << This is my currently working solution
            @post.save

            redirect PostN, post_num
        end
    end
    ...
end
...
```

When I assign something to `@post.user` using Camping in console mode, it is successful, but I can't seem to accomplish the same behavior in the controller otherwise. I made do by simply assigning the `@user.id` to the `user_id` property of the `Post` instance. However, I would like to figure out why the alternate method works in the Camping console and not when I'm simply running the webserver.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by assigning `nil` to `@post.user` prior to assigning `@user` to the same. I'm still trying to figure out why a simple assignment without odd workarounds won't work.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this is a problem with namespaces. In the code you show `User`is actually `Blog::Models::User`. In your controller the context is `Blog::Controllers`. Have you tried changing the code in the controller to?

```
@post = Blog::Models::Post.find(post_num)
@user = Blog::Models::User.find(@input.user)
...
```

Comment: Yes I did and that didn't work. Despite the different scope, Camping models are visible in the controller, so the fully qualified name isn't necessary. You would only need to use the full name if there is a class name conflict between a model and controller.

Comment: Bummer. I think it's very odd that it doesn't raise the error the first time you refer to User, so I still think it's a problem with namespaces and how Camping is handling them. Have you tried with a breakpoint before `@post.user = @user` and evaluating @user.class? I suggest using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. Seems when I was creating new `Post` records, I was not initializing the `User`. Thus, when assigning `@post.user` it would complain that the `user` property was uninitialized. The only problem I see is that an operation was attempted to be made on an oprhan `Post` record, which is invalid data according to the relationship with `User`.